# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable (While tryng to apply a function on Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply this function on a pandas dataframe. But I am getting this error. I'd like to know what does it mean, and how to rectify it?

```
def fill_age(x):
    Age = x['Age']
    Pclass = x['Pclass']
    Sex = x['Sex']

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 1:
            return 34.61 + np.random.normal(loc =0, scale = 13.61)
        elif (Pclass == 1) & (Sex == 'male'):
            return 41.2813 + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 15.14)
        elif (Pclass == 2) & (Sex == 'female'):
            return 28.72 + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 12.87)
        elif (Pclass == 2) & (Sex == 'male'):
            return 30.74 + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale= 14.79)
        elif (Pclass == 3) & (Sex == 'female'):
            return 21.75 + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 12.73) 
        elif (Pclass == 3) & (Sex == 'male'):
            return 26.51 + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale= 12.16) 
        else:
            pass
    else:
        return Age
train['Age'] = train['Age'].apply(fill_age)
```

Note: train is a pandas dataframe
[image]

Comment: The full traceback would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where:

`train['Age'] = train['Age'].apply(fill_age)`

is coming from, but I suspect ```train`` is actually a float not a dict.